# Why Is the Compiler Complaining About My Transform Argument to FlatMap?

Tags: generics, swift3, extension-methods, xcode8

I have defined a protocol and an Array extension. The compiler is reporting an error on the invocation of flatMap in the extension's encode method: **Cannot convert value of type 'T?' to closure result type '_'**

```
public protocol Encodable {
    typealias Properties = Dictionary<String, Any>
    func encode() -> Properties
    init?(_ properties: Properties?)
}

extension Array where Element : Encodable.Properties {
    func encode<T:Encodable>(type: T.Type) -> [T] {
        return flatMap{ T($0) } // <= Compiler Error
    }
}
```

- The compiler has obviously found the initializer defined in the Encodable protocol - T($0) will produce a T?.
- flatMap has an appropriate overload which should produces a [T].
- I have no idea what "**closure result type '_'**" might mean.

xcode 8.3 is using swift 3.1 (perhaps I should not have updated Xcode?)

Any ideas?

Comment: Try just `flatMap(T.init)`. Not only is it preferable, but it may also lead to a more useful error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiling your code in a small project, I can find another error:

> ```
> <unknown>:0: error: type 'Element' constrained to non-protocol type 'Encodable.Properties'
> ```

So, the constraint `Element : Encodable.Properties` is invalid and Swift cannot find a suitable initializer for `T($0)`. It is often found that Swift generates inappropriate diagnostics in case of issues related to type inference.

As far as I tested, this code compiles with Swift 3.1/Xcode 8.3:

```
extension Array where Element == Encodable.Properties {
    func encode<T:Encodable>(type: T.Type) -> [T] {
        return flatMap{ T($0) }
    }
}
```